# Getting Billing details of Subscription android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, recurring-billing

I am using InAppBilling version 3 in my app, I am able to purchase subscriptions using test account. Now my question is how do I know the billing details in my app againt one subscription plan. Suppose I have purchase one plan and it renews Daily, Is there any provision or method to know that renew is done to this product with details(like for ex. product_id, time, date, update, renewing_status...etc). I have refered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410640/google-play-in-app-billing-subscription-callbacks) link.

And the other thing is that do a user can subscribed to multiple subscription at a time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching quite a bit, finally I found my solution. Google don't provide **subscription order number** for test purchases(if you are using test account to test your application without going to production). It only provide **product_id, token, purchase_time, developer_payload, autoRenewing, package_name and purchase_state** as if Google don't send details to Play Billing server as it is not a real purchase. Still your can implement your own logic as it provide **autoRenewing = true**(if product is in renewal state) and **false**(if product is in non-renewal state) with **purchase_state = 0**(purchased) , **1**(canceled) and **2**(refunded). And one more thing I came to know after reading documentation of Google that, test user who has taken the subscriptions the recur on daily basis, but they will only get the same details, which they get while purchasing a test subscription plan.

It provide **order Id** for real purchases with other details. If your subscription is monthly and your **order Id** is **GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567** while purchasing the plan. Then next month Google append your **order Id** with **GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..0**(second month) , **GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..1** (third month) and so on. So you can track your renewal of purchases with **order Id** as described in [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html). Rest are same.

Comment: I Agree with you.Thank You.:)